# Can main() have an exception specification?

Tags: c++, c++11, program-entry-point, exception-specification

In standard C++, can the `main` function have an exception specification?

For example, is the following legal?

```
int main() noexcept {}
```

Comment: It is silly though. If an exception is thrown out of main the program exits with an exception backtrace. If a function throws something not in its exception specification, it does the same.

Comment: @ZanLynx actually  your first case calls `std::terminate`, and your second case calls [`std::unexpected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/unexpected).  By default, the latter calls the former, but that can be changed. Any "exception backtrace" would be an implementation-specific extension.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it completely is legal. There is no wording in the C++ standard (in [[basic.start.main]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main), [[except.spec]](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec), or elsewhere) that prohibits this.

Even in C++17 and later where exception specifications are part of the function type, `main` is only restricted in its linkage and return type according to [[basic.start.main#2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2):

> An implementation shall not predefine the `main` function. This function shall not be overloaded. Its type shall have C++ language linkage and it shall have a declared return type of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.

Comment: You might want to quote C++ 14 (N4140) [except.spec] 15.4/13 (or equivalent from other versions): "An *exception-specification* is not considered part of a function’s type." along with [basic.start.main] 3.6.1/2: "... `main` ... shall have
a declared return type of type `int`, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined."

Comment: @Angew But since C++17 noexcept-specification is a part of the function type.